# Learn Python the Hard Way ex4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm recently follow learn python the hard way to ex4 and a bit confused about it. I use python3.5.2
This is what I typed in my editor and it worked well:
 [image]

but when I open the file through terminal, it turned out like this:

```
('There are', 100, 'cars available')
('There are only', 30, 'drivers available')
('There will be', 70, 'empty cars today.')
('we can transport', 90, 'to carpool today.')
('we need to put about', 3, 'in each car.')
```

The result I expect is:

```
There are 100 cars available without the symbols.
```

Comment: Can you post your source code as text rather than as an image?

Comment: From the output, it looks like you're using Python 2.x, not 3.5.2.

Comment: Please read [**_Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?_**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 5):

Your editor and your terminal are using different versions of Python.

In Python 3+, printing a tuple (what you're doing essentially) separates elements by a space.

In Python 2.7, it prints as if it would print a tuple.

This likely is happening because you have both versions installed, but 2.7 appears first in your PATH, so when you invoke Python through the command line, that's what's used. To fix it, just edit your PATH to move the 3+ version up.

This is achieved by the following on Windows 10:

- Right click This PC > Properties
- Click Advances system settings, on the right
- Click Environment Variables...
- Double click the PATH user variable
- Locate the version of Python you want to be used by default (in your case 3.5.2 - should be in a folder named Python35)
- Click that, and click the Move Up button until it's above other Python versions
- Do the same for its Scripts folder

Comment: Thank you so much!! could you please tell me how fix it on mac?

Comment: owww. I just fixed it!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, and you have multiple python versions installed, which you obviously do, use the py console command to run the version you want.  Start with `py -h`.  If you have exactly 2.7 and 3.5 installed, `py -2` will run 2.7 and `py -3` will run 3.5.

Comment: It works now! Thank you!